# iPhone app does not work correctly on iPad after change from universal to iphone only

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

**How can I run iPhone apps on iPad after changing the target from an initial 'Universal' to 'iPhone'?**

I'm working on a game for iOS (iPhone) using Swift and SpriteKit. The game got rejected today for this reason:

> Reasons for Rejection: 2.10: iPhone apps must also run on iPad without
>   modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

After searching on StackOverflow I found out that it might have something to do with my `info.plist` file because at first my app was 'universal' and later I've changed it to iPhone-only.

It seems like there's something wrong with the aspect ratio of all the nodes. Take a look at the screenshots below. At the left side is the iPad-simulator and on the right there's the iPhone-simulator.

Maybe the game still thinks it is running on iPad because the nodes appear in 4:3 ratio?

**How can I run iPhone apps on iPad after changing the target from an initial 'Universal' to 'iPhone'?**

Please help. Thanks!

[image]

I've also added a screenshot of my `info.plist` file.

[image]

Comment: What size does your background node have? Also if you whant your app run only on Landscape delete those 2 (Item 0, Item 1 PORTRAIT)

Comment: Can you post the code where you create the scene?

Comment: @Darvydas This actually solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Darvydas' comment solved my problem.

> What size does your background node have? Also if you whant your app
>   run only on Landscape delete those 2 (Item 0, Item 1 PORTRAIT)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Apple requires that each app targeted on iPhone should run on iPad in the specific manner.

This usually looks like the app on iPad is not full-screen, it's surrounded by black frame that resembles the situation that the iPad is simulating iPhone.

My suggestion is to use size class now to make the app run full-screen on iPad and this should fix your issue with Apple.

Simply choose in your storyboard Regular Width and Regular Height, delete the existing constraints and set new ones.

More help [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started) and [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html) also might come in handy